# LocalDate private variables month and day short data type

Tags: java, localdate

In the source code of the LocalDate class I saw that the private instance variables month and day were **shorts** instead of **ints**.

[This is the Docs of the LocalDate class.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

** A short part of the source code **

```
private final int year;
private final short month;
private final short day;

private LocalDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = (short) month;
    this.day = (short) dayOfMonth;
}

public int getDayOfYear() {
    return getMonth().firstDayOfYear(isLeapYear()) + day - 1;
}

public int getMonthValue() {
    return month;
}

public int getDayOfMonth() {
    return day;
}
```

As you can see beside the variables themselve, the int data type is used for month and day. Why make it a short then?
And why not this?

```
private final short year;
private final byte month;
private final byte day;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all about the **storage**. When you create an object of LocalDate, it allocates some space in heap, the size of heap allocated is based on the type of instance variables you have. Here since month and day are declared as '**short**', 2 byte will be allocated for them, if it was declared as int , it will be 4 bytes each.

It doesn't matter the type of parameters, it will be automatically boxed to short from int when you assign the value.

Comment: That's also what I thought, but why didn't they save more space by making it short year, byte month, short day?

Comment: Might be a design consideration, ie, when programming for low level equipments, the word size will be 16 bits (can be 8 bits also for very low level embedded devices). At the same time for most of the computers it is 32bit word size. Even if its short, I think operations are in 32 bit , ie . registers will be 32 bit size, bus will be 32 bit, addressing will be for 32 bit word. 
So in case of computers we are not going to get the memory advantage except for short arrays.